# PyCharm does not automatically recognize a sqlite3 database inside a Django project

Tags: django, sqlite, pycharm

I am following a Django tutorial. After creating the project tictactoe, I opened it using PyCharm professional

[image]

According to some PyCharm tutorials the database should be automatically recognised and should appear on the database windows. This is not the case.

According to other PyCharm tutorials I should be able to drag the db.sqlite3 file into the database windows to automatically connect to the database and this is also not working.

Could someone guide me step by step and explain how do I connect to the DB and how I visualise its content?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a db you have to run the command python manage.py migrate in your command prompt or terminal

Comment: Is not already there? (db.sqlite3) forgive the trivial question

Comment: No, it is not. After each changes in your model you have to run this command after running python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: @bmons The file db.sqlite3 appears if you runserver though. PyCharm will display it in the project explorer but won't recognize it as a DB before migrate is ran. Why won't PyCharm get it from the .sqlite3 extension and just display an empty DB?

Answer (score 2):

You need to click the `+` button, then `Data Source`, and in your case, select SQLite from the dropdown. After that, in the new window, select the actual `db.sqlite3` file.